# How to make first item in spinner act as placeholder?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-adapter

Tried everything on the net but couldnt figured it out so i need some help..

All i want is first item in spinner act like placeholder / hint so its will be unselectable and readable as gray.

Mainactiviy

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.ulkeler, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        nereyetext.setAdapter(adapter);
```

strings.xml (where spinner items stored)

````
    <string name="app_name">Bus Booking App UI</string>
    <string-array name="ulkeler">
        <item>Gitmek istediğiniz yeri seçin...</item>
        <item>Türkiye</item>
        <item>Amerika</item>
        <item>İtalya</item>
        <item>Fransa</item>


    </string-array>

    <string-array name="ulkeler2">
        <item>Konumunuzu seçin...</item>
        <item>Türkiye</item>
        <item>Amerika</item>
        <item>İtalya</item>
        <item>Fransa</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>```

if i miss something to share for solution please inform me thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

Add dummy item in list **list.add("select item")**